# Bootstrap tabs: add / remove span inside active tab

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have bootstrap tabs set up so that I have 4 tabs with an active class on the anchor.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add some jQuery to add an additional span inside the active link.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>This is the current tab</span>Tab 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('ul li a.active').prepend('<span>Test - </span>');
```

if you want it to always be on the current tab, you would need to bind this to the anchor's click event, remove the old span and add it to the newly selected one.

Like this:

```
$('ul li a.active').prepend('<span class="activeSpan">Test - </span>');
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    var activeSpan = $('.activeSpan').remove();
    $(this).prepend(activeSpan);
});
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnuEE/)

Comment: Thanks you so much, that was pretty straight forward after all.

Comment: Is there a way to add a <span>Tab</span> to every li tab and just change the text to <span>Tab active</span>.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much Johnathan

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS, and then just style the "before" psuedo-element as if it were a span:

```
li a.active::before {
   content: "This is the current tab";
}
```